# Rename "growth" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [growth](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/growth) is very popular, but I feel it is not precise enough. Should we rename it "economic-growth", as that is what it currently stands for?

(tag excerpt reads "An increase over time in the quantity of goods and services produced within an economy.")

Comment: Do you have a view of the tags [tag:growth-theory], [tag:endogenous-growth], and [tag:balanced-growth]?

Comment: @Ubiquitous Well, economic-growth gives room for empirical questions, which growth-theory does not. They could in principle be merged (the latter has just 29 questions), but it feels not totally necessary. I think now one would mistake "growth-theory" by anything but economic growth theory. But growth in itself is too imprecise. There is just no need for super short tags. The other tags two seem fine as stand-alone to me, as they are quite a sub-field between the growth literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to merge [growth-theory](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/growth-theory) and [growth](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/growth) into a new [economic-growth](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-growth). As in my comment to Aleco's answer, I think the latter tag would be friendly to both theory and empirical questions.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion. Let's wait a day or two to see if any macro guys show up here to say otherwise and then do it.

Comment: Update: I have implemented this suggestion.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Great. Thanks. Looks good!

Answer (score 0):

Users are tag consumers, and they will go for the easiest. And I totally aggree that "growth" is a useless tag, being very general.

**My proposal, however tedious** (but we need to get serious about tagging): **re-tag all 120 questions tagged with "growth" into one of the three other related tags, and then purge the "growth" tag.**

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that you are putting empirical questions into the growth-theory tag. which is misleading. Why not instead remove the growth-theory tag and merge it with growth tag into economic-growth?

Comment: @LUCHONACHO this is also a valid approach.